# How to get difference of two timestamps?

Tags: javascript

```
if((ts2 - ts1) > 300000){
    return false;
}
```

I have two timestamps

```
new Date().getTime();
```

Both different and I want to calculate this difference. Any ideas on how to do this the easy way?

Comment: How do you want to calculate the difference? Number of seconds? Days?

Comment: @Joseph number of milliseconds

Comment: Create the time stamps with `Date.now()`. Then, just subtract to get the diff in milliseconds.

Comment: You should be able to subtract the timestamps directly, as you've done, to get the difference in milliseconds. Can you show us where ts2 and ts1 came from?

Comment: This is well documented in the date javascript docs. Did you look there already? What didnt work that you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it in seconds the try like this:-

```
var seconds = (_final.getTime() - _initial.getTime())/1000;
```

If you want in milliseconds:-

```
var milliseconds = (_final.getTime() - _initial.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

[getTime()](http://www.javascripture.com/Date#getTime) returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 so if you just subtract the results of the getTime() calls, you will get the difference in time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the difference between any two numbers using the minus (`-`) operator.

```
var difference = 123456 - 123455; // difference = 1
```

In your particular case the two numbers happen to be timestamps, corresponding to the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC, but it doesn't matter, they are still numbers.